# cPanel Server Incorrect URL Resolve

Tags: linux, apache, curl, cpanel, wget

My cPanel server is resolving a URL wrong. The website `example.com` is hosted on my cPanel server at ip `1.0.0.1`. In a script I am attempting a cURL command to `cp.example.com` which is hosted on another server at `2.0.0.2`. My server is resolving `cp.example.com` to the IP of `1.0.0.1`. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your dns settings for cp.example.com are not visible on the host where you are running your script. You should check the dns settings for cp.example.com. You may also want to contact the Cpanel support

Answer (score 0):

When you make a cURL request from a source hosted on your cPanel server the IP for the domain is first resolved locally, if it's not found in your Server's DNS zones it will be resolved from your configuration at /etc/resolv.conf

You can test to see which IP your server is resolving this by logging via SSH and pinging it

### Executed from your cPanel Server

```
ping cp.example.com
```

I can think of two workarounds for this issue:

**If example.com's DNS zone is hosted in your cPanel account**

1. Go to cPanel -> Zone Editor
2. Open the DNS zone for example.com
3. Find the A record for cp.example.com
4. Change it to 2.0.0.2

**If you have root** - edit your WHM / cPanel Server's /etc/hosts file

```
root@server #: vim /etc/hosts
// 2.0.0.2 cp.example.com
```